# Does the quadratic formula always work for a quadratic?

Tags: quadratics

Does the quadratic formula always work for a quadratic? If it does, why are the factors sometimes imaginary numbers?

Comment: 1) Yes, *as long as your working on a field with characteristic* $\;\neq2\;$ . (2) If you're working on the reals, that's because there don't exist square roots of negative real numbers *within the real numbers field*, but **there are such** within the complex numbers field.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, the formula always works for quadratic equations, because from the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, one can derive the formula $x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ manually. [Here is a video on Youtube showing such a derivation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDmRYfma9C0)

The factors become imaginary numbers if $b^2-4ac<0$, which means $b^2-4ac$ is negative. And taking the square root of a negative number produces an imaginary number.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why the factors are sometimes imaginary or complex is because not every parabola crosses the x-axis in the real plane.  For an example, the equation $y=x^2 +1$ has as a vertex (and minimum) $(0,1)$ ,and goes up from there.   So there cannot be any real roots.   The actual roots ($\pm i$) are in the complex plane, and the fundamental theorem of algebra states that a polynomial always has a full complement of complex roots (Up to repetition)